# SQL Server extracting multiple parents

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, hierarchical-data

We have a dilemma whereby we have a hierarchy of records, each item in the hierarchy can be of any number of different types. The final node in the hierarchy is a site, further up the hierarchy i.e. parents there are conceptual items like Area Director, Managing Director and so on. The items in the hierarchy are NOT at fixed levels that is a Managing Director in one branch maybe at level 3 and at Level 7 in another branch.

So we have a report that needs to display each site and along with it the sites relevant managers of which there are seven and the result set contains 1500 sites, each one different. We have a scalar function that will return the sites parent of a specific type which works fine other than it creates a read cost in excess of 8,000,000 units which is impacting the rest of the system from a performance perspective doh!

Has anybody got any ideas as to how we can extract this information in a more efficient manner, so that the read costs are reduced and the time the report takes to generate is significantly reduced.

So the bit that is causing us issues is within our final select statement, something along these lines: -

```
SELECT 
   [SiteName], FetchSiteHierarchyItem(BusinessID, 'OD') AS OperationsDirector, 
   FetchSiteHierarchyItem(BusinessID, 'MD') AS ManagingDirector

 ...... and so on
```

Each call to `FetchSiteHierarchyItem` takes approximately 700 reads depending on the number of levels we have to traverse back, so obviously 1500 rows x 7 formats x 700 reads equates to 7,350,000 reads aaaaargh!

Thanks in advance

Andy

Comment: [There is a datatype for this now...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677290(v=sql.105).aspx)

Comment: Can you show us the schema? The implementation of "FetchSiteHierarchyItem"? As it stands, your question cannot be objectively answered (other than by recommending the hierarchyID datatype).

Comment: You my friend are a legend I believe this is the answer to our problems hierarchyid I cannot understand how we have never stumbled across this before!